# Punctuation with two sets of lists

Tags: lists

I am puzzled how punctuation would work with two lists in a sentence. Am I using the semi-colon correctly here?

*"Those strawberries were ripe, red, and juicy; fruits with great taste, texture, and color."*

Or would it be more proper to use an em dash?

*"Those strawberries were ripe, red, and juicy—fruits with great taste, texture, and color."*

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*"Those strawberries were ripe, red, and juicy; fruits with great taste, texture, and color."*

This sentence would be better with a colon, since the phrase after your semi-colon is an incomplete sentence.  Then fruits clearly refers to strawberries.

Your second is fine also, with the dash.

Comment: I'm not sure it is "an incomplete sentence" - I would understand it as "[they were] fruits with ..." I tend to agree with Will Self on this "I like them - they are a three-quarter beat to the half and full beats of commas and full stops. Prose has its own musicality, and the more notation the better."